# django: build a class based view that set a session object and call another view

Tags: python, django, django-views

is possible to build a class based view that set a session object and call another view? I did this with a form, but I need to set a session object just calling a url.

Now my files are:

url.py

```
  urlpatterns += [
    path('test/<int:pk>/set', views.testv, name='testset'),
  ]
```

views.py

```
def testv(request, pk):
    request.session["test"] = pk
    return render(request, "test_01.html")
```

This works, called through "test/01/set" and render the test_01.html page. I need to call tha same link but call another class after setted  the request.session["test"] object.

Thanks

Comment: "Is it possible?" Yes. Have you tried anything? If so, you should show what you tried so we can help you.

Comment: This is a good start using a function-based view. Now implement a class based view.